# Spark not saving all data to redshift

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

The following code loads data from S3, cleans and removes duplicates using SparkSQL, and then saves data using JDBC to Redshift. I have also tried using spark-redshift maven dependency and getting same result. I am using Spark 2.0.

What I cannot understand is how when showing the result loaded in memory, the sum is the expected number, however when Spark saves to Redshift, it's always less. Somehow not all records are saved, and I do not see any errors in STL_LOAD_ERRORS either. Anybody encountered this or have any ideas to why this happens?

```
        // Load files that were loaded into firehose on this day
    var s3Files = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("s3://" + job.getAWSAccessKey + ":" + job.getAWSSecretKey + "@" + job.getBucketName + "/"+ job.getAWSS3RawFileExpression + "/" + year+ "/" + monthCheck+ "/" + dayCheck + "/*/" ).rdd

    // Apply the schema to the RDD, here we will have duplicates
    val usersDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(s3Files, schema)

    usersDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("results")

    // Clean and use partition by the keys to eliminate duplicates and get latest record
    var results = spark.sql(buildCleaningQuery(job,"results"))
    results.createOrReplaceTempView("filteredResults")

    // This returns the correct result!
    var check = spark.sql("select sum(Reward) from filteredResults where period=1706")
    check.show()

    var path = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    println("s3://" + job.getAWSAccessKey + ":" + job.getAWSSecretKey + "@" + job.getAWSS3TemporaryDirectory +  "/" + path) 

    val prop = new Properties()

    results.write.jdbc(job.getRedshiftJDBC,"work.\"" + path + "\"",prop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jdbc` means that Spark will be trying to do repeated `INSERT INTO` statements - which is *massively* slow in Redshift. That's why you're not seeing entries in `stl_load_errors`.

I'd suggest that you use the `spark-redshift` library instead. It's well tested and will perform better. https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Example (showing many options):

```
my_dataframe.write
   .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
   .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://my_cluster.qwertyuiop.eu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/my_database?user=my_user&password=my_password")
   .option("dbtable", "my_table")
   .option("tempdir", "s3://my-bucket")
   .option("diststyle", "KEY")
   .option("distkey", "dist_key")
   .option("sortkeyspec", "COMPOUND SORTKEY(key_1, key_2)")
   .option("extracopyoptions", "TRUNCATECOLUMNS COMPUPDATE OFF STATUPDATE OFF")
   .mode("overwrite") // "append" / "error"
   .save()
```

Comment: Yes I used both, as I explained. I used JDBC to eliminate the possibility of an issue coming out of spark-redshift.

Comment: Maybe some files are skipped. Prevent the `spark-redshift` library from deleting the staging data and check `stl_load_commits` against a list of the S3 files.